# Delphi -- Casting an integer to a typed pointer?

Tags: delphi, pointers, syntax, delphi-7

I'm having some trouble with the syntax of Delphi.

I have a record:

```
type
  TMyType = record
    ....
  end;
```

and a procedure:

```
procedure Foo(bar:Integer);
var
  ptr : ^TMyType
begin
  ptr := bar //how to do this?
end;
```

How do I properly cast an integer to a pointer of TMyType?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
type
  PMyType = ^TMyType;

procedure Foo(bar: Integer);
var
  ptr: PMyType;
begin
  ptr := PMyType(bar);
end;
```

Comment: Ah I wasn't for sure a new type would be required. I figured it was like C where "typecasts" are purely optional

Comment: @Earlz typecasts aren't optional in C. You would need to cast to assign an integer to a pointer variable in C.

Comment: Pascal object is a strongly typed language, so casts are mandatory between different types.

Comment: @TridenT C is strongly typed too. And in fact C and Delphi are similar in the way that any pointer is assignment compatible with `void*`/`Pointer`.

Comment: @David I meant typedef, which is basically the C equivalent

Comment: @Earlz OK, I see what you meant now.

Comment: Do note that this will fail on Win64 because there the pointer type is 64-bit and integer is still 32-bit

Comment: @Marco Yes, for 64 bit you would use NativeInt rather than integer.

Comment: When tMyType has a field like string[n] your solution seems to not work.

Comment: @SHiN you'll need to ask a question with lots of details

Answer (score 3):

You must **cast it explicitely** with the new type:

```
  type PMyType = ^TMyType;

  ptr := PMyType(bar);
```

or

```
  ptr := pointer(bar);
```